# does not show the default image when there is an error loading the product image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify and Nuxt.js.
After searching for products, a table is displayed with their list in the rows of which an image of each product is shown.
If the product does not have an image and a `404 error` appears, then the default image should appear, which is stored in `/assets/images/nofoto.png`.
I also use `v-hover` for these images.
When the table is normally loaded, the image is not displayed by default,
but when you hover the mouse using `v-hover` to the place where the picture should be, then it appears.
If you remove `v-hover`, then the image by default does not show at all.
Tried using `:eager="true"` but it didn't work.
I thought the reason was dynamic `:src` and Webpack converts it to normal `src`, but attempts to fix it have failed.
Maybe I was wrong and that's not the point.
Tried looking for an answer in the Vuetify documentation but couldn't find anything on the matter other than `:eager`.
Can you please tell me what could be the reason that `nofoto.png` is not displayed immediately without hovering over `v-hover`?

```
import getImageURL from "@/js/images";

methods: {
    getImageURL(id, def) {
        return getImageURL(id, def);
    },
```

```
<template v-slot:item.productID="{ item }">
        <v-hover  v-slot="{ hover }">
         <div class="wrap-image">
            <v-img  :class="{ 'show-img': hover }"
                       class="imageItem"
      :src="item.error ? require('../../assets/images/nofoto.png') :getImageURL(item.productID, true)"
       v-on:error="item.error = true" content-color-bg="transparent" contain alt="Your image description">
         </v-img>
            </div>
              </v-hover>
                </template>
```

```
.show-img{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.wrap-image{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 85px;
    max-width: 100px;
}
.imageItem {
    align-self: center;
    max-width: 80%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```